# Monitor randomly reboots - could it be Ubuntu fault?

Tags: display

Recently bought a new widescreen display/TV combo for my Ubuntu system. It has a weird issue that when viewing huge colorful images fullscreen (or close to full screen) display reboots - turns off, displays logo and continues to display whatever it was displaying before. Sometimes I can get into infinite reboot loop. Tried connecting it through HDMI<->DVI and VGA - results are the same. Also tried using integrated video card - it still crashes.

Has anyone seen similar issues? Is it possible, that this is a defect of PC/OS combo, but not display? Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems impossible, that PC could crash monitor.
The same PC/OS combination works normally with my old 17" LCD.
Maker says that hardware is not faulty.

OS: Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit
Video: ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT (VGA, DVI)

UPDATE: A little follow up - same issues on Windows system on different PC. I narrowed it to a set of images, when I quickly switch between them monitor freezes after some time. Now I'm wondering how is it possible for specific images to force monitor reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the screen to another system if possible. If the problem doesn't persist it's related to your current system and the manufacturer of your screen is right. If it does persist, then:

Contact the manufacturer again or contact place of purchase. Stress that you have this problem with 2 different video cards (highly unlikely if the screen isn't to blame)